ESP32: call `WiFi.begin` inside a constructor triggers the RTCWDT_RTC_RESET
I hope you are all doing great.
As the title says, I'm using an ESP32 and when I try to call the WiFi.begin method within a class's constructor, the ESP32 watchdog is triggered and reboots the device and this keeps going on a loop. Here is the log from the serial terminal:
17:54:00.179 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
17:54:00.179 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
17:54:00.179 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
17:54:00.179 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
17:54:00.179 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:4832
17:54:00.179 -> load:0x40078000,len:16460
17:54:00.179 -> load:0x40080400,len:4
17:54:00.179 -> load:0x40080404,len:3504
17:54:00.179 -> entry 0x400805cc
17:54:08.535 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
17:54:08.535 -> 
17:54:08.535 -> rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
17:54:08.535 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
17:54:08.536 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
17:54:08.536 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
17:54:08.568 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:4832
17:54:08.568 -> load:0x40078000,len:16460
17:54:08.568 -> load:0x40080400,len:4
17:54:08.568 -> load:0x40080404,len:3504
17:54:08.568 -> entry 0x400805cc

This is the test code:
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* WIFI_SSID = "ssid";                                         
const char* WIFI_PASS = "password";

class dummyClass {
  public:
    dummyClass() {
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
    }
};

dummyClass dm;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("Setup function");
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
  delay(10000);
  Serial.println("loop finished");
  Serial.println("");
}


I can call WiFi.begin anywhere outside a class constructor and it works perfectly. I'd like to know why is this happening.
I have a hunch that it has something to do with the Wifi module not being fully initialized yet at the hardware level, but this is just a hunch.
Also, is there a way to properly call WiFi.begin in a class constructor?
Thanks in advance.

Not a lot of information there, and compilers for embedded systems may have peculiar rules, but the constructor for dm probably runs before the call to setup, so nothing has been initialized.

For Arduino, both setup() and loop() are within a main(), and there are initiliazation code before before setup() is run, when you create an instance of your C++ Class, you are trying to run code that still not yet been initialized on the global space before main() is run, don't try to run any code in a class constructor, this is why almost all Arduino C++ class has a method begin() or init(). The constructor should only do initilazation.

Thanks both of you for your clarification
